# Ubuntu 12.4 и древний ASUS K50C

Tags: ubuntu, vga

Здрасте, господа
Решил поставить на свой старый как мамонт ноутбук какой-либо дистрибутив линукс, чтобы разбираться с ним по немногу (сейчас знания ограничены несколькими командами по управлению файлами в терминале, хотелось бы всё-таки освоить)
Нагуглил, что последняя версия, на которую можно будет поставить видео-драйвера (на ноуте старая и непопулярная встроенная видяха SiS) - это 12.04. Её и поставил. 
Что странно, при установке системы и при "Try Ubuntu" разрешение экрана 1024*768. 
Но после установки - 600 * 480 (т.е. работать с системой невозможно). 
Поставил драйвер по этой инструкции http://forum.ubuntu.ru/index.php?topic=132992.75 , но после перезагрузки система пыталась запуститься только в Low-Graphics Mode, который даже не получилось включить, в итоге можно только в консоли что-то делать.
В подобных вещах я полный ноль, так что прошу больно не бить. Скажите пожалуйста, почему после установки системы не доступно разрешение экрана как при её установке и что делать чтоб можно было с ней работать?
Большое спасибо

Comment: попробуйте рецепты из [этой темы](http://forum.ubuntu.ru/index.php?topic=264797.0)

Comment: оно, спасибо, раза с четвёртого получилось.